# AWS RDS PostgreSQL - Indexes being dropped automatically shortly after creation

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm creating indexes via pgAdmin for my PostgreSQL database hosted via AWS RDS with the following command:

```
CREATE INDEX team_idx_teamid ON team ("teamId");
```

Which returns the response:

```
Query returned successfully in 1 secs 575 msec.
```

And it is displayed in pgAdmin UI:

[image]

After a few minutes it disappears. Looking at the event logs in AWS I see the following message:

```
2021-06-21 11:21:58 UTC:13.58.56.170(51704):[16657]:STATEMENT: DROP INDEX "team_idx_teamid"
```

I can't find anything related to why indexes are being dropped or cleaned up in my google searches. Anyone got any ideas of what is going on?

Many thanks

Comment: No, and I don't think Amazon goes around dropping your indexes. Perhaps add more data to `log_line`prefix` so that you can see which user does this, and from where the session hails.

Comment: Are you sure this is RDS?  That log entry does not match the format that amazon claims it uses for RDS and aurora: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/working-with-rds-and-aurora-postgresql-logs-part-1/

Comment: @jjanes That log statement was in the 'error/postgresql.log.2021-06-21-13' file accessed from the RDS portal. I removed my user@dbname from log statement

Comment: The DROP index statement was coming from my username.

Comment: So something on 13.58.56.170 seems to have your password and is deleting your indexes.  If you don't know what it is, I think I'd be changing my password, then setting up different accounts for different things.

Comment: Not sure if it's that because the index is deleted a few minutes after, every time I create it. I will change password etc just as precaution to see if it changes.